# Golang delve, how do you start the debugger and have the application that you are debugging start?

Tags: debugging, go, delve

I am trying to setup a headless delve debugger that I can attach to remotely.

I am unable to find a way to launch a debugging server that doesn't pause the application I am debugging.

I have been using `dlv attach --headless=true --listen=:2345 attach 32` but this pauses the process.
Alternatively I could use `dlv --headless=true --listen=:2345 exec app` if this allowed the app binary to run.

I don't know if the `init` file can do something like this? I cannot find any documentation on what that actually is.

Comment: Check if the new option `--continue` might help: See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46331836/6309).

Answer (score 7):

If you consider [delve issue 145](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/245), that might be a feature, not a bug:

> I can't see the value of starting an actual debug session without pausing unless you're simply relying on providing an `init` file (to load breakpoints / tracepoints) and then want to immediately continue execution, which you could do by writing a continue command at the end of the `init` file.
>
> You can already set tracepoints without stopping the program indefinitely with the `trace` subcommand, which takes a pid flag.

---

That being said, with [Delve 1.3.0](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-2019-08-27) (August 2019, 2 years later):

[go-delve/delve issue 245](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/245) is resolved by [PR 1585](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/pull/1585)

> ### `cmd/dlv`: add `--continue` to continue process on launch/attach
>
> Add `--continue` option for `attach`, `debug`, `exec`, and `trace`, to issue a `continue` on start.
>
> The main use case for this feature would be to start a headless delve server (for example within a container)