# How to show app's original logs while using delve debugger with kubernetes and golang?

Tags: go, debugging, kubernetes-helm, delve

I'm using Kubernetes and helm chart to deploy some microservice applications in a system.
Other services will use Netcat to wait for the **waiter-service** until it is up, but this **waiter-service** service seems not to work properly when started by delve, so I want to check its logs.

The dockerfile's entry point is like below:

```
/dlv --listen=:40000 --log --log-output=rpc --allow-non-terminal-interactive=true 
--api-version=2 exec /server -- appname --config=configfile.yaml
```

The logs i received are like below:

```
2022-08-24T13:22:11Z debug layer=rpc serving JSON-RPC on new connection
2022-08-24T13:22:11Z debug layer=rpc <- RPCServer.SetApiVersion(api.SetAPIVersionIn{"APIVersion":2})
2022-08-24T13:22:11Z debug layer=rpc -> *api.SetAPIVersionOut{} error: ""
2022-08-24T13:22:11Z debug layer=rpc <- RPCServer.IsMulticlient(rpc2.IsMulticlientIn{})
2022-08-24T13:22:11Z debug layer=rpc -> *rpc2.IsMulticlientOut{"IsMulticlient":false} error: ""
2022-08-24T13:22:11Z debug layer=rpc (async 3) <- RPCServer.State(rpc2.StateIn{"NonBlocking":true})
2022-08-24T13:22:11Z debug layer=rpc (async 3) -> rpc2.StateOut{"State":{"Pid":14,"Running":false,"Recording":false,"CoreDumping":false,"currentThread":{"id":14,"pc":4652512,"file":"/usr/lib/go-1.18/src/runtime/rt0_linux_amd64.s","line":8,"function":{"name":"_rt0_amd64_linux","value":4652512,"type":0,"goType":0,"optimized":true},"goroutineID":0,"ReturnValues":null,"CallReturn":false},"Threads":[{"id":14,"pc":4652512,"file":"/usr/lib/go-1.18/src/runtime/rt0_linux_amd64.s","line":8,"function":{"name":"_rt0_amd64_linux","value":4652512,"type":0,"goType":0,"optimized":true},"goroutineID":0,"ReturnValues":null,"CallReturn":false}],"NextInProgress":false,"WatchOutOfScope":null,"exited":false,"exitStatus":0,"When":""}} error: ""
2022-08-24T13:22:11Z debug layer=rpc <- RPCServer.Recorded(rpc2.RecordedIn{})
2022-08-24T13:22:11Z debug layer=rpc -> *rpc2.RecordedOut{"Recorded":false,"TraceDirectory":""} error: ""
```

But when I run it with normal command

```
/server appname --config=configfile.yaml
```

My expected logs are like:

```
2022/08/24 07:43:43 maxprocs: Leaving GOMAXPROCS=16: CPU quota undefined
2022-08-24T07:43:44.976Z    INFO    database/pool.go:35 database configuration  {"MaxConns": 8, "RetryCount": 10, "RetryInterval (seconds)": 5}
2022-08-24T07:43:44.976Z    INFO    v4@v4.15.0/conn.go:355  Dialing PostgreSQL server   {"host": "postgres-infras.emulator.svc.cluster.local"}
2022-08-24T07:43:44.980Z    INFO    nats/jetstream.go:335   nats jetstream connected
2022-08-24T07:43:45.090Z    INFO    zap/grpclogger.go:92    [core][Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel Connectivity change to READY    {"system": "grpc", "grpc_log": true}
```

The question is how can I read the actual logs to know the reason why **waiter-service** is not working when others can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the below options:

```
 --continue --headless
```

Related issue: [Go delve --continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856590/golang-delve-how-do-you-start-the-debugger-and-have-the-application-that-you-ar)